# angular 5 reset chart js bar in same component

Tags: angular, angular5, chart.js

i have component to show detail of my products i used a horizontalBar chart in component but when i view other product it keeps pervious chars bar and new bar will append to it . i tried to null chart bar values and also i deleted artingArr but it not working how can i reset the chart and redraw it when product data changed?

my chart is like this :
in ngAfterinit():

```
    for (let rate of this.product.product_ratings) {
      this.sum += rate.rating;
      this.ratingArr.push(rate.rating);
      let n = this.product.product_ratings.length;
      let nn = this.sum / n;
      this.product.peopleCount = n;
      this.product.between = Math.round(nn * 10) / 10;
    }


   new Chart(<HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById("user-rev-chart"), {
      type: 'horizontalBar',
      data: {
        labels: ["5 star", "4 star", "3 star", "2 star", "1 star"],
        datasets: [
          {
            fill: true,
            label: false,
            backgroundColor: ["#a1a7b3", "#a1a7b3", "#a1a7b3", "#a1a7b3", "#a1a7b3"],
            data: [this.fivestar, this.fourstar, this.threestar, this.twostar, this.onestar]
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        responsive: false,
        legend: {display: false},
        title: {
          display: false,
          text: ''
        },
        scales:
          {
            yAxes: [{
              // barPercentage: 0.4,
              barThickness: 20,
              barPercentage: .5,
              categoryPercentage: .2,
              isFixedWidth: true,
              //Number - Pixel width of the bar
              barWidth: 20,
              gridLines: {
                display: false
              },
              ticks: {
                min: 0,
                stepSize: 1,
                fixedStepSize: 1,
              }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
              display: false,
              gridLines: {
                display: false
              },
              ticks: {
                min: 0,
                stepSize: 1,
                fixedStepSize: 1,
              }
            }],
          }
      }
    });
```

ngInit():

```
  ngOnInit() {

    if (this.isActive() && this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
      this.changeCaptcha();
    }
    this.all = null;
    this.cur = null;
    this.onestar = null;
    this.twostar = null;
    this.threestar = null;
    this.fourstar = null;
    this.fivestar = null;
    this.ratingArr = [];


  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to get the 2d context.

Template :

```
<div class="chart-container" fxFlex="80">
      <canvas id="currency"></canvas>
</div>
```

Component:

```
  private displayCurrencyGraph(currencyEntry: CurrencyEntry) {
    const currencyCanvas: any = document.getElementById('currency');
    const currencyCanvasContext = currencyCanvas.getContext('2d');
    ChartBuilder.buildChartLine(currencyCanvasContext,this.data );
  }
```

ChartBuilder:

```
static buildChartLine(canvasContext, data){
    new Chart(canvasContext, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {data} 
}
```

From your code, you are missing `getContext('2d')` call from your canvas. If you add that, it should work.

You must call destroy() method on context and then assign new dataset.

Comment: i think my problem is diffrent .. my code will draw the chart i dont have any problem about that .. i want  re draw chart when i clicked other product ... pervious chart should be forget .  this time it will draw chart by keeping last chart bars

Comment: Well in that case you must remove the old items (which you don't want to draw) from the dataset which you provide to your chart. Have you tried instead of referencing the this product from your class, with actual passing the object to the method responsible with drawing the chart ? I see you are referring this.product.

Comment: im setting dataset values to null on ngOninit and i also tried null product property

Comment: ok show me when you finished i will give you +1 and also i will accept your answer it depend on your example

Comment: Have a look here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zpcfuz . Please try to refresh the context by selecting new option (it is something wrong with ChartJs dependency). What I had to do was to call destroy() method on current chart. So on your code, when you get the chart by selecting it by id, call destroy() method before assigning new dataset.

Comment: well done this answer is correct answer and i accept this from you thankyou my friend

Comment: Glad I helped you.

Comment: i still have the problem

Comment: you used a click event function to destroy chart by im using routerLink to show new content the solution not work in my case

Comment: can you please extend your stackblitz example and change click funtion to router link 
i used `<a routerLink="/detail/{{ si?.slug }}"><h1>{{ si?.title }}</h1></a>`

the slug will load another new contents from server